# Combining the metrics by request variable in Kibana

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

Say I need to find 95th and 99th latency of an API with endpoint: "/api/v1/merchant/{merchantId}/logo".

In Kibana I tried searching: "/api/v1/merchant" AND "/logo". But, it returned multiple results, one for each merchantId.
[image]

How to search such that single URL is returned which combines the metrics for all merchantIds to give the output?

Comment: kibana4 had its eol in 2018 and probably has significant vulnerabilities...

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is to filter for `"api v1 merchant * logo"` (mixing wildcards and string query to preserve the order) which is not possible at the moment. But if the filter `"api v1 merchant" and logo` is correct (aka you don't have APIs like `/api/v1/merchant/logo` without the id) then there is a solution.

You need a new visualization: just filter for the query and not aggregate the results by `API.keyword`.

Comment: We have this endpoint with the {merchantId} as request variable. So {merchantId} is there for every url. Like: 
/api/v1/merchant/1/logo,
/api/v1/merchant/2/logo,
/api/v1/merchant/3/logo

Comment: @AnkitSingodia then you have to produce a new table filtering for API.leyword: ("api v1 merchant" and logo).